# Why does Results.Json special-case null (and can I get it to stop doing that)?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, minimal-apis

Consider the following minimal repro example using the default ASP.NET Core template:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

// Content-Type application/json, Body: true
app.MapGet("/True", () => Results.Json(true));

// Content-Type application/json, Body: "string"
app.MapGet("/String", () => Results.Json("string"));

// Content-Type application/json, Body: {"someProperty":"someValue"}
app.MapGet("/Object", () => Results.Json(new { SomeProperty = "someValue" }));


// expected: Content-Type application/json, Body: null
// actual: no Content-Type header, zero-length Body
app.MapGet("/Null", () => Results.Json(null));


app.Run();
```

As you can see, `Results.Json` always yields a Content-Type of `application/json` and a body containing the json-serialized version of the first argument, **except** in the case of null (which is annoying, because it means I need to treat this special case in my client differently as well).

I know that I can work around this by creating my own version of `Results.Json`, but **I'd like to understand *why* this happens**. After all, the developers of the `Results` class apparently went the extra mile to implement a special-case logic for `null`, so they might have had a good reason for doing that (which I don't understand yet). Unfortunately, [the documentation has not been helpful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.results.json).

---

Note:

- I know that I don't need `Results.Json` for the first (`/True`) and the third (`/Object`) case. I do need it for the second case, because otherwise ASP.NET will return text (Content-Type text/plain) instead of a JSON string, which would mean yet another special case in my client.
- `app.MapGet("/Null2", () => (object?)null);` *does* return the expected result (a JSON-encoded `null`).

Comment: I suppose, why do you need a content type when there is no content? Sounds like a question for the devs perhaps.

Comment: Note that, if nothing else, it's *consistent*, in that all of the result returning implementations exit early if the value they've been asked to write is `null`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Well, `app.MapGet("/Null2", () => (object?)null);` *does* return the expected result (a JSON-encoded `null`). I added this observation to the question, in case it helps.

Comment: I meant all of the implementations you'll get by calling methods on the `Results` class - e.g. `BadResult` and `Content` do this same thing.

Comment: Why this happens? Because that's how `JsonHttpResult` object is implemented. Null is ignored, not written to body, and it doesn't set content-type. We can only guess motivation behind such decision. Whatever it was I believe it is a mistake, it is inconsistent with how Json works.

Comment: @DavidG well, you may ask: why do we need `null` Json to begin with? And actually I do think it is redundant. But it exists, and someone actually may treat `null` differently from empty content. Otherwise what's the point of `null`? Therefore I strongly believe that `Results.Json` should handle it consistently with Json spec.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to body to contain the JSON literal null

This can't be done via `Results.Json` because it explicitly does nothing for `null` value - [source code](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Results/JsonHttpResultOfT.cs,103).

You can return null as object:

```cs
app.MapGet("/Null", () => (object?)null);
```

Or explicitly serialize and return content:

```cs
app.MapGet("/Null", () =>
    Results.Content(JsonSerializer.Serialize<string?>(null), MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json")));
```

As for why - I can only guess here - mine would be "perfromance", maybe there is a case in TechEmpower benchmarks which allows such return, so shortcutting makes sense =)

Answer (score 2):

The only other way I could figure out how to get the null JSON value was using JsonElement:

```
var jsonNull = JsonDocument.Parse("null").RootElement;

app.MapGet("/", () => Results.Json(jsonNull));
```